# jsdocs3 No docs generation

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc3

This is my first time using jsdocs3 and I am not able to generate my documentation.
I created a file **app.js** and inserted the following comments:-

```
/**
 *  Main file - All modules are loaded.
 *  @author My Name
 *
 */
```

Then I ran the command **./node_modules/jsdoc/jsdoc.js ./app/app.js -r -d docs/** and the result is shown below:-

[image]

I have also tried the above command with the --debug param and I could see that jsdocs3 is able to parse the document and gets completed without any errors.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsdoc` generates it's document on both syntax parsing and `jsdoc` comment parsing. 
You need some function/object/module definitions in your file that `jsdoc` may recognize.

Either a module export:

```
/**
 * Fooer
 */
module.exports.foo = function() {

};
```

A class definition:

```
/**
 * Some class.
 * @constructor
 */
function SomeClass() {

    /**
     * Foo it
     * @param x data
     */
    this.foo = function(x) { };

};
```

You may also define a file itself:

```
/**
 * Awesome module.
 * @author John Doe
 * @file test.js
 */
```